# Как в golang можно реализовать постоянно чтение файла?

Tags: golang

Как можно реализовать следующее?
Имеется текстовый файл, время от времени в него добавляется информация из стороннего сервиса. Мне нужно постоянно считывать данный файл и по мере того, как в него добавляются новые строки - выводить эти новые строки в консоль

Comment: так невозможно сделать - при открытии файла, вы его копию выгружаете в свою оперативную память(или часть копии) и работаете с ней. После работы при закрытии файла - изменения записываются на ПЗУ. Для чего вам нужно это?

Comment: @Space Researcher
 Человек чуть ниже предоставил библиотеку, которая очень неплохо справляется с данной задачей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрые люди уже написали [библиотеку](https://github.com/nxadm/tail), которая следит за обновлениями в файле. Есть [пример](https://github.com/nxadm/tail/blob/master/examples/01-tailAndPrint/main.go), как печатать новые строки из файла

Я проверил - работает

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nxadm/tail"
)

var logFile = "log.log"

func main() {
    t, err := tail.TailFile(logFile, tail.Config{Follow: true})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for line := range t.Lines {
        fmt.Println(line.Text)
    }
}
```

Этот пример прикрепляется к файлу `log.log` и читает оттуда новые строки.
Я написал скрипт, который раз в секунду пишет в `log.log` новую строку

```bash
cnt=0;while true; do echo $(( ++cnt )); date >> log.log; sleep 1; done
```

Вот вывод программы

```
...
Thu Jun  8 01:42:13 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:14 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:15 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:16 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:17 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:18 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:19 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:20 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:21 KST 2023
Thu Jun  8 01:42:22 KST 2023
...
```

Пример не останавливается, исправно печатает новые строки.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)